# Which Nginx and which config file is used

Tags: nginx, configuration, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Phusion Passenger module for Nginx. There was Nginx installed in `/usr/sbin/nginx`. The installer gem downloaded Nginx sources and compiled them with Passenger support into `/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`. I copied this file into `/usr/sbin/nginx`.

So currently I am in doubt which Nginx is running and which config file I should edit.

Is there some way to determine the location of actually used Nginx and which configuration file does it use?

Comment: A good answer weren't possible without a good question. Please upvote both if you would like to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shall be able to see the master process with:

```
florin@vm:~$ ps aux | grep nginx
root       884  0.0  0.0  76944  1308 ?        Ss   10:28   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
```

Then execute:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -V 2>&1 | grep --colour=auto conf
```

It shall give you a `--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` somewhere around there.

Comment: The `-V` flag will show the location of the conf file that Nginx was complied to use (i.e. the default), but it's possible that it's running another one, either supplied on the command line with `-c` (which `ps aux` would reveal), or another means, e.g. see [how can i change nginx Configuration file path](https://serverfault.com/questions/821284/how-can-i-change-nginx-configuration-file-path).

Answer (score 15):

```
~# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using below command:

```
   sudo nginx -t
```