# how can i change nginx Configuration file path

Tags: nginx, configuration, openam

i have installed nginx in ubuntu16.04, and check that Configuration file location is **/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf**

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -V 2>&1 | grep --colour=auto conf
```

then Show Configuration file path:

```
 --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I am working on Install **openam nginx Webagent** [link](https://github.com/hamano/nginx-mod-am), this **nginx_agent** have one **nginx.conf** file

**nginx_web_agent install path:**

```
   /opt/nginx_agent
```

**nginx_web_agent nginx.conf path:**

```
   /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf
```

nginx_web_agent use that **nginx.conf** file,

How can i change nginx **default nginx.conf** file to **nginx_web_agent  nginx.conf** file

for example:

nginx Configure use **/opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf** instead of **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

Suggest me How can i do that?

Answer (score 16):

`/usr/sbin/nginx -V` shows the initial configure script parameters, not necessarily the actual parameters that are running.

To use an alternative configuration file, instead on the default one, you can set the `-c` flag ([man nginx](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nginx)) :

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -c /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf
```

Ubuntu 16.04 uses `systemd` to manage services, so you will need to change `systemd` parameters for `nginx` service :

1. Edit `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`
2. Add `-c` flag where required :

   ```
   ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
   ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
   ```
3. Reload the `systemd` manager configuration :
   `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Start `nginx` service :

   ```
   service nginx start
   ```
5. Check `nginx` service parameters :

   ```
   systemctl status nginx.service

   ...
   2411 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf -g daemon on; master_process on
   ...
   ```

This is the way i would do it.

Comment: Do not edit the system `nginx.service` directly. It may be restored whenever you upgrade the package. Instead, provide your overrides in `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/whatever.conf`.

Comment: @krisFR I have used ubuntu16.04 docker,  docker have issue to `Since systemd isn't running as init inside your docker container, there's no daemon to process your start and stop commands.`  reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169403/systemd-and-systemctl-within-ubuntu-docker-images  , so, Suggest me Any alternative way to change nginx configuration path.